# remove a certain pattern from strings

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a csv file i want to read into my IDE, and the values are of the format:

```
Boston (MA), New York City (NY, CT, NJ)
New York City (NY, CT, NJ), Philadelphia (PA, NJ)
...
```

I'll read the line in and split the string at the comma, creating an array of strings, but I only want the city names

I want to remove everything that has brackets around it. is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Java regex isn't able to deal with nested parenthesis if any. However, for your particular case, since parenthesis are not nested, it's possible to split the string on comma.

Answer (score 1):

With the `find()` method, you can use this pattern:

```
[^(,]*(?:\\([^)]*\\)[^(,]*)*
```

[demo](http://fiddle.re/pxk5jn)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using a [Regular Expression](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm):

```
String fileLineString = "Boston (MA), New York City (NY, CT, NJ)";

final Pattern REMOVE_BRACKETED = Pattern.compile("\\(.+?\\)");
Matcher matcher = REMOVE_BRACKETED.matcher(fileLineString);
String res = matcher.replaceAll("").replaceAll(" , ", ",").trim();
String[] cities = res.split(",");

//Display the cities Array in Console...
for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(cities[i]);
}
```

The console output will be:

```
Boston
New York City
```

The RegEx pattern to use basically does this, locate any open parentheses `\\(` along with any single or more characters (except newline) regardless of how many `.+?` until the closing parentheses `\\)` is encountered.

We then run this pattern through the **Matcher.matcher()** method.

We then declare a String variable (named **res**) and initialize it with the returned string from the **Matcher.replaceAll()** method which replaces every sub-sequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern with the given replacement string, we use **""** within the method to indicate we want to replace what was matched. We then apply the **String.replaceAll()** method (as in: `.replaceAll(" , ", ",")`) to clean up the unwanted whitespaces before and after the comma delimiters, and then finally we apply the **String.trim()** to remove any leading or trailing whitespaces from the overall result string should there be any.

Now we simply create a String Array named **cities** using the **String.split()** method. The rest of code I'm pretty sure you can figure out.

**UPDATE:**

Simply because this sort of bugged me a bit...

The above code works adequately for Strings which contain parenthesis which are NOT Nested but fails if there are nested parenthesis. If you find that your strings do from time to time contain nested Parenthesis then you can utilize the method below which removes even nested parenthesis.

```
String fileLineString = "Boston (MA), New York City (NY, (CT), NJ)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\([^()]*\\)");
String wasString;
String res = fileLineString;
do {
    wasString = res;
    res = pattern.matcher(wasString).replaceAll("");
} while (!wasString.equals(res));

res = res.replaceAll("\\s+,\\s+", ",").trim();
String[] cities = res.split(",");

//Display the cities Array in Console...
for (String citie : cities) {
    System.out.println(citie);
}
```

Output to console will be:

```
Boston
New York City
```

If you would like to add other brackets to the regular expression like {}, [], or even <> then you can do this:

- Parenthesis Only:  `"\\([^()]*\\)"`
- Parenthesis and Curly Brackets:  `"\\([^()]*\\)|\\{[^{}]*\\}"`
- Parenthesis, Curly Brackets, and Square Brackets:
  `"\\([^()]*\\)|\\{[^{}]*\\}||\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]"`
- Parenthesis, Curly Brackets, Square Brackets, and Chevron Brackets:
  `"\\([^()]*\\)|\\{[^{}]*\\}||\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]|\\<[^<>]*\\>"`

With the last one, it doesn't matter which of the four brackets are encountered within your string they and their contents will be removed from the string even if any one or all are nested within one another.

Answer (score 0):

If I handle this issue, I will use IDE regex replace all the ")," to ")\n", and then you will transform the document to multiple lines which separated by a comma. Then you can get the Country and Cities easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try something like this.

**Sample Code**

```
String str = "Boston (MA), New York City (NY, CT, NJ),New York City (NY, CT, NJ), Philadelphia (PA, NJ)";
Pattern bracket = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\(.*?\\),?");
Matcher matcher = bracket.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1).trim());
}
```

It will return only City name.